# Python: run service after hostapd

Tags: python, linux, wifi, python-2.6, access-point

I have been working on a project for a few weeks now and I encountered something (probably stupidly simple) I can't figure out!

```
import os
os.system("service hostapd start && hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf")
os.system("service someservicethatIuse start")
```

When I start `hostapd` the script pauses because it enables an access point. I tried running it with `xfce4-terminal --tab -e "hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf" --tab -e "service someservicethatIuser start"` but it doesn't seem to work :-/

(Language: Python 2.6)

Comment: Why do you use Python for this if all you are doing is running shell commands?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about hostapd, but usually it's enough to run `service foo start` to start a service and it *does not* block.

Anyways, you could run shell processes in prallel using `sh` `&` operator:

```
import os
os.system("service hostapd start && hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf &")
os.system("service someservicethatIuse start")
```

Comment: when i run it it first start the service and then it start hostpad

Comment: If the other service depends on `hostapd` being up, it's a useful feature that the script waits for `hostapd` to actually start successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *-B* option when you start hostapd, it should run it in the background

> $~/hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf